# Component/JPanel repaint() method issues

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I am trying to make Conway's game of life but I am having issues using the `repaint()` method. I have created a class that extends JPanel and I am calling `super.paint(g)` when I override paint, plus I am not overriding the `repaint()` method, yet I have had no luck. The main method I test this in is the here (please excuse my terrible identifiers):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class YouThinkThisIsAGame extends JFrame {
private Life facebook;

public YouThinkThisIsAGame() {
    super("I'm Blue da ba dee da ba die");
    Life kyle = new Life();
    add(kyle);
    //setSize(kyle.getALife()[0].length * 5, kyle.getALife().length * 5);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    setMaximumSize(getSize());
    setMinimumSize(getSize());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    YouThinkThisIsAGame stuff = new YouThinkThisIsAGame();
    while (true) {
        stuff.facebook.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the JPanel extending class is here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Life extends JPanel {

private Cell[][] grid;
Color life;

{
    life = new Color(0, 175, 0);
    initializeGrid(1300, 800, 0.025);
}

public void paint(Graphics G) {
    super.paint(G);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) G;
    drawGrid(g2d);
}


/** Me attempting to be funny */
public String getLife() {
    return null;
}

/** Also trying to be funny */
public Cell[][] getALife() {
    return grid;
}


public void drawGrid(Graphics2D g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j].isLiving) {
                g.setColor(life);
                //g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            g.fillRect(i * 5, j * 5, 5, 5);
        }
    }
}

/** Allocates a new grid of cells of the requested dimensions and 
 * sets each cell in the grid to a random living/dead state.
 * The desired percentage of living cells is passed as a
 * parameter.
 * 
 * @double percent roughly, the percentage of cells that should
 *   be initialized as alive
 */
public void initializeGrid(int rows, int cols, double percent) {
    grid = new Cell[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new Cell();
            double x = Math.random();
            if (x > percent) {
                grid[i][j].setLiving(false);
            } else {
                grid[i][j].setLiving(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

/** Displays the contents of the grid to the standard output.
 */
public void displayGrid() {
    for (Cell[] cellRow : grid) {
        for (Cell c : cellRow) {
            if (c.isLiving()) System.out.print("0");
            else System.out.print("1");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

/** Updates the value of each cell in the array according to
 * the rules of life: 
 * If the cell is currently living --
 *   if fewer than two neighboring cells are alive, die (loneliness)
 *   if two or three neighboring cells are alive, live
 *   if four or more neighboring cells are alive, die (overcrowding)
 * If the cell is currently dead -- 
 *   if precisely three neighboring cells are alive, become alive
 */
public void updateGrid() {
    Cell[][] gridCopy = new Cell[grid.length][grid[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            Cell c = new Cell();
            c.setLiving(grid[i][j].isLiving);
            gridCopy[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < grid.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < grid[i].length - 1; j++) {
            int adjacentAlive = 0;
            if (i == 2 && (j == 4 || j == 3)) {
                System.out.print("");
            }
            if (i == 3 && j == 4) {
                System.out.print("");
            }
            if (gridCopy[i - 1][j - 1].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (gridCopy[i][j - 1].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (gridCopy[i + 1][j - 1].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (gridCopy[i - 1][j].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (gridCopy[i + 1][j].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (gridCopy[i - 1][j + 1].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (gridCopy[i][j + 1].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (gridCopy[i + 1][j + 1].isLiving) {
                adjacentAlive++;
            }
            if (adjacentAlive == 3) {
                grid[i][j].setLiving(true);
            }else if (adjacentAlive == 2) {

            } else {
                grid[i][j].setLiving(false);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

/** Convenience method for setting the grid values.
 * 
 * @param grid a two dimensional table of Cells
 */
public void setGrid(Cell[][] grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Life life = new Life();
    life.initializeGrid(15, 40, 0.25);
    life.displayGrid();
    while (true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        life.updateGrid();
        life.displayGrid();
    }
}

class Cell {
    private boolean isLiving;

    public void setLiving(boolean isLiving) {
        this.isLiving = isLiving;
    }
    public boolean isLiving() {
        return isLiving;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two main methods, and I'll assume that the one that you run is the one within the `YouThinkThisIsAGame` class. If so, you never call `updateGrid()` on the Life object from this main method (but you do in the *other* main method), and so the grid never will update.

Suggestions:

- Create a Thread within the main method,
- Pass in a Runnable that has the `while (true)` loop.
- Within that loop, call `updateGrid()` on the visualized Life instance
- And call `repaint()` on the Life instance.
- Call `start()` on that Thread after creation.
- Note that you're better off drawing within the JPanel's paintComponent override, not the paint method.
- And call the `super.paintComponent(...)` within that override.
- Always precede your override method with an `@Override` annotation to have the compiler check that you are in fact overriding the method.
- Fix the NullPointerException that you *now* tell us about. You never initializing or using the `facebook` field but instead are using a shadow variable, kyle, declared inside of the YouThinkThisIsAGame constructor. This is the only viable Life instance going.
- So get rid of the kyle variable, instead initialize and use the facebook field.
- And avoid directly accessing any fields of an object. Instead go through public methods of the class, and you should create a method just for this, for calling `updateGrid()` and `repaint()` again on the ***visualized*** Life instance (that's why I mentioned visualized above -- it's key).

e.g., something like:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class YouThinkThisIsAGame extends JFrame {
    private Life life;  // renamed to life

    public YouThinkThisIsAGame() {
        super("I'm Blue da ba dee da ba die");

        // no -- don't create a new Life variable!
        // Life kyle = new Life();
        // add(kyle);

        life = new Life(); // initialize and use the **field**
        add(life);  // and place it into the JFrame

        setSize(500, 500); // better to have Life override getPreferredSize
        setVisible(true);
        setMaximumSize(getSize());
        setMinimumSize(getSize());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void updateLife() {
        life.updateGrid();
        life.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final YouThinkThisIsAGame stuff = new YouThinkThisIsAGame();
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                stuff.updateLife();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about the main methods, the main method in Life just creates a game of life by printing 1's and 0's to the console. I should have made this clear in the original post, (sorry, I'm new to this), but my code is throwing a NullPointerException when I call the repaint() method in YouThinkThisIsAGame, I even changed YouThinkThisIsAGame's paint method to just be super.paint(g) and draw a rectangle and it still gave me the null pointer. Would this fix it? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @TeymorBuckley: the NPE is obvious -- you're never initializing or using the `facebook` field! You instead are using some shadow variable, `kyle`,  inside of the YouThinkThisIsAGame constructor, why?